# why am i getting this error with cgcontext

Tags: ios, cgcontext

i am getting this error, usually when i long press in a uitextfield and the magnifying glass appears
there are many such errors reported at the same time

e.g.
: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

the only drawing code i have is as follows

what's wrong with this code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); //context
CGContextBeginPath (context);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context,3);
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2);//get the view centre

//get the polygon points

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x-70,rect.size.height - 140 );
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x + 130, rect.size.height - 140);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x - 70, 100);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x- 70, rect.size.height - 140);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x - 50, rect.size.height -140);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x - 50, rect.size.height - 160);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x - 70, rect.size.height - 160);


CGContextClosePath(context);//close the path
//[[UIColor clearColor] setFill];//set the colour for fill
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];//set the line color
CGContextDrawPath (context, kCGPathStroke);//draw

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you the one calling the `drawRect:` method? You shouldn't do this, you should call `setNeedsDisplay`, and the Application will call `drawRect:` at the appropriate time.

If you call the `drawRect:` method yourself there won't be a CGContext pushed to the context stack so the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return `nil`, and you will get the error that you're seeing.

Comment: i have this draw rect statement in a class on its own - i then in my storeyboard have a uiscrollview to which i added a uiview. - i then changed the class of this uiview to the class name which contains the drawrect statement - thats all ive done - i dont call drawrect myself, or call set needs display anywhere. this seems to have worked for me pre ios 7 so what could be wrong this time?

Comment: The problem is that `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is returning nil. I don't suppose that there is somewhere else that you've called `UIGraphicsPopContext` without a matching push?

Or possibly a `CGContextRestoreGState` without a matching save (although I think that raises an exception immediately).

Comment: thanks james - im sure you are right that the context is nil, but im not sure how to resolve that issue. the code works just fine with no errors if compiled in xcode 4.3 but fails when i compile in xcode 5 with ios7.  how do i force creation of the graphic context. i noticed if i put UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size) in my view did load statement of my main view controller, the problem goes away, but is this the correct solution to this problem or not? - hope you can advise.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this. You could set a break point on `UIGraphicsPopContext ()` and make sure that neither your code nor a third party library is calling this without a matching `UIGraphicsPushContext()`. If you've made a ImageContext somewhere else you shouldn't use the pop function to remove it you should use `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.